# Attempting to run multiple simulations of the Gillespie algorithm for a set of stochastic chemical reactions in less than 10 minutes

Tags: python, performance, numpy, simulation

I have written Python code that generates a plot. In the code below, when I set `maxtime = 0.1`, the program takes ~50s and when I set `maxtime = 1`, it takes ~420s. I need to run it for `maxtime = 1000`.

I am familiar with Python syntax and writing "Matlabic" code, but am lost in writing natively "Pythonic" code. As a result, I need help in **optimizing this code for runtime, specifically in the two outer `for` loops and inner `while` loop.**

1. How can I make the code suitable for use with Numba or Cython?
2. If that's not possible, do I need to use functions, or `map`, or `lambda` statements?

Unfortunately, my Spyder IDE for Python is freezing up every time I try to profile the code. I would include those details if I could!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
import math

maxtime = 1
Qpvec = np.logspace(-2,1,101,10)
lenQp = len(Qpvec)
delta = 1e-3
P0vec = Qpvec/delta
SimNum = 100
PTotStoch = np.zeros((SimNum,lenQp))
k_minus = 1e-3
k_cat = 1-1e-3
k_plus = 1e-3
zeta = 1e-4
D0 = 10000
kappa_M = (k_cat+k_minus)/zeta
QpDeg = np.true_divide(1000*D0*Qpvec*k_cat,1000*Qpvec + kappa_M)

for lenQpInd in range(0,lenQp):
    for SimNumInd in range(0,SimNum):
        Qp = Qpvec[lenQpInd]
        P0 = P0vec[lenQpInd]
        DP0 = 0
        P = math.floor(P0)
        DP = DP0
        D = D0
        time = 0

        while time < maxtime:
            u_time = pl.rand()
            u_event = pl.rand()
            rates=np.array([Qp,zeta*P*D,k_minus*DP,k_cat*DP])
            PTot = P + DP
            kT = np.sum(rates)
            tot = np.cumsum(rates)
            deltaT = -np.log(1-u_time)/kT
            time += deltaT
            if time > maxtime:
                PTotStoch[SimNumInd,lenQpInd] = PTot
                break
            elif u_event*kT < tot[0]:
                P += 1
            elif u_event*kT < tot[1]:
                P -= 1
                DP += 1
                D -= 1
            elif u_event*kT < tot[2]:
                P += 1
                DP -= 1
                D += 1
            elif u_event*kT < tot[3]:
                DP -= 1
                D += 1   

PMean = PTotStoch.mean(axis=0)
PStd = PTotStoch.std(axis=0)

plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(Qpvec,PMean,marker=".") 
plt.errorbar(Qpvec,PMean,yerr = 2*PStd, xerr = None)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Are you using Python 2 or 3? There are minor relevant differences.

Comment: Maybe be worth reading: [Optimizing Python in the Real World: NumPy, Numba, and the NUFFT](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2015/02/24/optimizing-python-with-numpy-and-numba/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pythonic code follows [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), mostly you need to stick to one type of variable format.
In Python they are:

- `snake_case` variables. (functions are variables).
- `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` constants.
- `CammelCase` classes.

There are a few white space conventions that you didn't follow, such as spaces around operators, and one space after commas.
But all in all you have some nice style.

---

First things first, don't use pylab. It's not supported,
in-fact I could only find one archive page about it that said to use matplotlib instead.

I assume that `pylab.rand` is the same as `numpy.random`.

---

Due to the above style concerns I found your code hard to read.
But there are also a lot of variables that are written and read once.
This makes the code harder to read, as then you have to remember senseless names such as `u_event` or `kT`.

---

I found the inner part of the while loop hard to read, instead split, the time changes and changes in `p`, `d` and `dp`, into two sections.
This made it easier for me to read and understand.

---

After doing the above I ran a profiler over the code, and using numpys array and `cumsum` were dramatic performance sinks.
To resolve this I implemented `cumsum` in Python, and used a Python array.

This lead to a 260% increase in speed on `max_time = 0.1`.
Note that I don't test the generation of `P0_VEC` as I made it a global variable in my code, but didn't in yours.
(So mine has an unfair advantage).

Also as @oliverpool says in the [comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117903/42401#comment219544_117971), you can get a [speed up from using functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11241523/3207406). (I put both my code and your code in a function, so the timings wern't *extreemly* unfair.)

---

I doubt that you can make the code much faster, as it's seems to be \$O(n)\$ already.
And with my change you are doing 309057 function calls, or 214921 a second.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
random = np.random

# testing functions remove them from this script.
PROFILE = True
TIME = True

# Global constants
DELTA = 1e-3
SIM_NUM = 100
K_MINUS = 1e-3
K_CAT = 1 - 1e-3
ZETA = 1e-4
D = 10000
QP_VEC = np.logspace(-2, 1, 101, 10)
KAPPA_M = (K_CAT + K_MINUS) / ZETA
P0_VEC = QP_VEC / DELTA


def gillespie(max_time=0.01):
    p_tot_stoch = np.zeros((SIM_NUM, len(QP_VEC)))
    for len_qp_ind in range(len(QP_VEC)):
        qp = QP_VEC[len_qp_ind]
        p0 = int(P0_VEC[len_qp_ind])
        for sim_num_ind in range(SIM_NUM):
            p = p0
            d = D
            dp = time = 0

            while True:
                tot = [qp, ZETA * p * d, K_MINUS * dp, K_CAT * dp]
                for i in range(3):
                    tot[i + 1] += tot[i]
                kt = tot[-1]
                time += -np.log(1 - random.random()) / kt
                if time > max_time:
                    p_tot_stoch[sim_num_ind, len_qp_ind] = p + dp
                    break

                event_kt = random.random() * kt
                if event_kt < tot[0]:
                    p += 1
                elif event_kt < tot[1]:
                    p -= 1
                    dp += 1
                    d -= 1
                elif event_kt < tot[2]:
                    p += 1
                    dp -= 1
                    d += 1
                elif event_kt < tot[3]:
                    dp -= 1
                    d += 1

    return p_tot_stoch


if __name__ == '__main__' and PROFILE:
    import cProfile
    cProfile.run('gillespie()')

if __name__ == '__main__' and TIME:
    import timeit
    def gillespie_dot_one():
        return gillespie(0.1)
    def gillespie_one():
        return gillespie(1)
    print('gillespie(0.01)*100 = ', timeit.timeit(gillespie, number=100))
    print('gillespie(0.1)*10 = ', timeit.timeit(gillespie_dot_one, number=10))
    print('gillespie(0.1) = ', timeit.timeit(gillespie_one, number=1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p_tot_stoch = gillespie()
    p_mean = p_tot_stoch.mean(axis=0)
    p_std = p_tot_stoch.std(axis=0)

    plt.figure(0)
    plt.plot(QP_VEC, p_mean, marker=".")
    plt.errorbar(QP_VEC, p_mean, yerr=2 * p_std, xerr=None)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: [Putting it in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11241523/3207406) (as you did) is also a good performance idea!

Comment: @oliverpool Wat. Well I never knew that!

Comment: This is fantastic. I am working my way through understanding the changes you made, and I will try to use Numba on the function `gillespie` to speed it up further (for `maxtime = 1000`). How can I view the plot figure? I am not used to seeing the `if __name__ == '__main__':` structure!

Comment: @abscissa As currently posted I kept it with the profiler and timers running. To turn them off change `PROFILE=True` and `TIME=True` both to false, after some time (130 seconds?) you should get the graph. And `if __name__ == '__main__'` is a way to prevent your code from running if you import it by accedent, I always use it to be safe.

Comment: @JoeWallis Unbelievable. Initially, the program took ~50 seconds for `maxtime = 0.1`. With your changes, ~12 seconds. With Numba added (`from Numba import jit` and `@jit` before `def gillespie(max_time=0.01):`), **4 seconds!**

Comment: @abscissa That's really fast... Numba seems pretty good! You may want to unaccept my answer, as I've seen people change entire functions of Python code to one numpy function before... (I don't know numpy, and so I would refer you to SuperBiasedMan's comment)

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know any of the packages you're using, so I can only give some brief notes.

I spotted one area of optimisation you're missing out on. You set `Qp` and `P0` on every single iteration of `SimNumInd`. But they should only change for each new value of `lenQpInd`, so you should move them to the outer loop, and also call `math.floor` there rather and just assign `P` from that.

```
for lenQpInd in range(0,lenQp):
    Qp = Qpvec[lenQpInd]
    P0 = math.floor(P0vec[lenQpInd])

    for SimNumInd in range(0,SimNum):
        P = P0
```

A couple points on redundancy.
`range(0, n)` is the same as `range(n)`. `range` always defaults to starting with 0 if you pass only one parametere, so you can just use `range(lenQp)`.

This seems totally redundant:

```
    DP0 = 0
    DP = DP0
```

`DP0` is never used, so why not just set `DP = 0` and save yourself a line?

Lastly your names don't make this code easy to follow. Even if Qp, P0 and DP0 match with notation you normally use for this data, they make for very unreadable code. Using actual words to describe your code will improve readability and make it easier for people to follow what's happening, which will, in turn, allow people to find optimisations easier.

Comment: Glad to help, and thanks for accepting my answer. But you may want to wait a bit for other people before you accept. Sometimes answers on Code Review take a while, and people can be dissuaded from reviewing when they seen an accepted answer. I generally recommend waiting at least a day. In particular, this is just a small answer with brief notes, someone more familiar with the libraries you're using may be able to give you a more thorough review.